# How could I use the function which I gave as an argument?

Tags: python, sockets, arguments

```
def error_block(inner_func):
    def dec_f(client,*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal inner_func
        try:
            return client.inner_func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print("연결에 실패했습니다.")
            for socket in client_list:
                if not_con(socket):
                    remove(socket)
            raise CError

    return dec_f
```

In the code, the `client` argument is a socket from the module `socket`, and the `inner_func` function which I gave as another argument is a `socket.socket.send` so I figured that it will be functioning as 
`client.send()`, but the Log says

```
*AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'inner_func'*
```

so inner_func isn't interpreted as a argument I've sent to the function, but a function that has to be in the socket class.
so, how can I use inner_func as a function I've sent?

Comment: I think you would need to do `innerfunc(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: The reason for being able to do what @D.BenKnoble mentioned is closure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: Please show a complete example of how you want to use `error_block` from elsewhere, and what should happen as a result.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your comments!!! i've used error_block as
    
send_tmp = error_block(socket.socket.send)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.send(...)` is essentially short for `socket.socket.send(client, ...)`. So you should do:

```
return inner_func(client, *args, **kwargs)
```